# Why won't my loop ask for nextLine() after the first try?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

In my program, the loop asks and executes correctly on the first loop. Upon starting the second iteration and so forth of the loop, it skips asking the user for a message to be encrypted. Why is that?

```
    public void startProgram() {
    boolean quit = false;
    while (!quit) {
        String plaintext = new String();
        System.out.println("Enter a message to be encrypted.");
        plaintext = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Now enter a shift value for your message.");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        cc.encryptMessage(i, plaintext);
        System.out.println("Here is your encrypted message: ");
        cc.printEncyrption();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here is your original plaintext message: ");
        cc.decryptMessage(i);
        cc.printPlaintext();
        System.out.println("\n");

    }
}
```

Here is a sample of what happens in the output:

Enter a message to be encrypted.

the sky

Now enter a shift value for your message.

4

Here is your encrypted message:

xli woc

Here is your original plaintext message:

the sky

Enter a message to be encrypted.

Now enter a shift value for your message.

At the beginning of the second iteration of the loop, it doesn't allow the user to input a message to be encrypted. I believe it has something to do with the nextLine() method.

Comment: `while (false)`?  That won't be entered at all

Comment: It should be while (true)